# How do I solve "lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content" in the following context?

Tags: struct, compiler-errors, hashmap, rust, borrow-checker

I have the following struct in my lib.rs

```
pub enum ConfigurationSource {
    StringContent(String),
    FileContent(PathBuf)    
}

pub struct ConfigurationBuilder<'a> {
    config: Value,
    bundles: HashMap<&'a str, &'a Vec<ConfigurationSource>>    
}

impl<'a> ConfigurationBuilder<'a>{
    pub fn new(base_source: &ConfigurationSource) -> ConfigurationBuilder{
        let base_config: Value = from_str("{}").unwrap();

        let mut config_builder = ConfigurationBuilder{
            config: base_config,
            bundles: HashMap::new()
        };

        config_builder.merge_source(&base_source);

        return config_builder;
    }

    //more code here

    pub fn define_bundle(&mut self, bundle_key: &str, sources: &Vec<ConfigurationSource>){
        self.bundles.insert(bundle_key, sources);
    }
}
```

I do not want the bundles Hashmap in the ConfigurationBuilder instances to own the `bundle_key`s or `source`s passed into the `define_bundle` method.

I get the following two compile errors at build time

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src\lib.rs:67:41
   |
67 |         self.bundles.insert(bundle_key, sources);
   |                                         ^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 27:1...
  --> src\lib.rs:27:1
   |
27 | / impl<'a> ConfigurationBuilder<'a>{
28 | |
29 | |     pub fn new(base_source: &ConfigurationSource) -> ConfigurationBuilder{
30 | |         let base_config: Value = from_str("{}").unwrap();
...  |
89 | |     }
90 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method
 body at 66:5
  --> src\lib.rs:66:5
   |
66 | /     pub fn define_bundle(&mut self, bundle_key: &str, sources: &Vec<ConfigurationSource>){
67 | |         self.bundles.insert(bundle_key, sources);
68 | |     }
   | |_____^

error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src\lib.rs:67:29
   |
67 |         self.bundles.insert(bundle_key, sources);
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 27:1...
  --> src\lib.rs:27:1
   |
27 | / impl<'a> ConfigurationBuilder<'a>{
28 | |
29 | |     pub fn new(base_source: &ConfigurationSource) -> ConfigurationBuilder{
30 | |         let base_config: Value = from_str("{}").unwrap();
...  |
89 | |     }
90 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the method
 body at 66:5
  --> src\lib.rs:66:5
   |
66 | /     pub fn define_bundle(&mut self, bundle_key: &str, sources: &Vec<ConfigurationSource>){
67 | |         self.bundles.insert(bundle_key, sources);
68 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input parameters for `define_bundle` have lifetimes that the compiler does not know either meet, or outlive the ones defined for the struct.

Telling the compiler they expect the same lifetimes will do the trick:

```
pub fn define_bundle(&mut self, bundle_key: &'a str, sources: &'a Vec<ConfigurationSource>) {
    //                                       ^^----------------^^ same lifetimes as the struct fields expect
    self.bundles.insert(bundle_key, sources);
}
```